# Add target & rel without javascript

Tags: php, jquery, drupal, target, rel

I have some links I need to add `target="_blank"` and `rel="noFollow noReferrer"`. I do not have acess to core code so the only way I managed to do this is with jquery.

My HTML is.

```
<div class="tLink">
  <p>
    <a href="http://linkhere.com" title="tLink title here">tLink</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

My jQuery code:

```
$( '.tLink p a' ).attr( 'target', '_blank' );
$( '.tLink p a' ).attr( 'rel', 'noFollow noReferrer' );
```

However this will not work if the end user does not have javascript enabled in the browser. So, its there any other way to do this with php? Or in a last case inside the `template.php` file of the drupal theme?

Thanks

Comment: do you mean you want to render the page with these attributes or do you want to dynamically change them when a button is pressed / field is complete ?
When you say 'core code' do you mean HTML / CSS or the server code ?

Comment: I want to render it on the page. By 'core' I mean the HTML. I do not know php language yet, only very few basics so far. :(

Comment: _However this will not work if the end user does not have javascript enabled in the browser._...This would be really bad in terms of web 2.0 as ajax is in charge of todays web developments.

Comment: @Jai errr, no...it's still, correctly, a legal requirement in many countries that websites work without javascript enabled. Planning for UI without AJAX is an absolute necessity. And _damn_ Tim O'Reilly for making that phrase popular, 'Web 2.0' means absolutely nothing!

Comment: @Jai I can spot user with javascript disabled in google analytics, plus read Clive comment before mine. Using a method other than ajax it's just a background security in my perspective, I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 99% of cases you'll be able to simply override [`theme_link()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/theme_link/7) in template.php:

```
function MYTHEME_link($variables) {
  $variables['options']['attributes']['target'] = '_blank';
  $variables['options']['attributes']['rel'] = 'noFollow noReferrer';

  return '<a href="' . check_plain(url($variables['path'], $variables['options'])) . '"' . drupal_attributes($variables['options']['attributes']) . '>' . ($variables['options']['html'] ? $variables['text'] : check_plain($variables['text'])) . '</a>';
}
```

I say 99% because the premise relies on every module in your installation 'behaving' itself, and using the `l()` function to prepare links. If any don't, you'll probably need to patch each module separately.

Also bear in mind that the above code will nuke any existing target/rel attributes (not append to them), so your logic might need to get a bit more complicated to compensate.

Comment: Your answer seams to be the proper method and I'm inclined to use it. Can I target an HTML class using it?

Comment: Maybe...if the class names are available to you they'll be in `$variables['options']['attributes']['class']`; if the right ones are there a simple `in_array()` would do. If you mean like the jquery selector in your question, then no - this function just produces the link, not the surrounding html.

Comment: Your answer works but in all links (even the internal ones). I need to target specific links with specific html class or id, only two links per page. The links does not have html class per se, only the surrounding element can have it.

Comment: Yep, the specific classes and ids will be in the attributes array. If they're not, you're out of luck, and you'll need to address each one as an individual concern, work out where it's coming from, and alter it separately. There's no magic solution here, either you have the context available in the theme_link function to make your choice, or you'll need to alter considerably more code elsewhere

Comment: I will mark you answer correct because I recognise your second comment (three comments above) would work if I had a class in the link. If some user needs something similar with a class in their links then they can see it here. I will try to change the link somehow and give it a class to use the `$variables['options']['attributes']['class']`. Thank you for your time.